# Formula for continuous poisson process model

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a stochastic model that looks like this:

[image]

Now if this model were **discrete-time**, I would just sample bernoulli trials, and I could write a difference equation that looks like this:

$$ x_{t+1} = x_t + b $$

with $b \sim Bernoulli(p)$, so b taking on the values $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with $1-p$.

Or alternatively

$$ \Delta x = b $$

(Code showing what I mean:

```
x = np.zeros(1000)

for t in range(1000-1):
    x[t+1] = x[t] + np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.02, size=1)

plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

produces
[image]
)

#### Question

What would be the **continuous-time** counterpart of this model? I am unsure how I could define this model with poisson / exponential distributions, and using $dx$ instead of $\Delta x$.

And secondly, once I have this continuous-time counterpart, how can I discretise it for simulation? Or would the discretised part be the same as described above?

Comment: With a small enough time increment, $\lambda \Delta t <1$. Let $p=\lambda \Delta t$, and $B_i$ be a sequence of IID Bernoulli’s with parameter $p$. Then $N_{t_i}=N_{t_{i-1}}+B_i$ and $N_0=0$ gives a discrete realization of $N$ over the time interval $[0,t]$ at the times $t_0,t_1,\dotsc t_n$, with $t_0=0$ and $t_n=t$, which will approach a continuous path as $\Delta t$ shrinks. Here, we use $\Delta t = t/n$, for an equally spaced time discretization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a sequence of random arrival times $(\tau_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and sum up the indicators up to $t$. That is $Y_t=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}(\tau_n)$. For example, you can use the exponential distribution to simulate $\tau_k-\tau_{k-1}\sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ IID, thus obtaining the sequence of arrival times on the nonnegative real line. Here is a coded example.

```
import numpy
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp 

def Yt_process(t,arrival_times):
    return numpy.sum(numpy.where(arrival_times<=t,1,0))

N = 100
intensity_lambda = 10
diff_arrival_times = scipy.stats.expon.rvs(size=N,scale=1/intensity_lambda)
arrival_times = numpy.cumsum(diff_arrival_times)

# plot of the process on a fine discretized time grid

grid_length = int(1e+05)
t = numpy.linspace(0,1,grid_length) # in [0,1]
Yt = numpy.zeros(grid_length)
for j in range(0,grid_length):
    Yt[j] = Yt_process(t[j],arrival_times)
    
mp.plot(t,Yt)
mp.xlim((0,1))
mp.show()
```

Comment: THank you. I see the similarities to http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/jgatheral/jumpdiffusionmodels.pdf. But what I dont understand, both in the linked doc and your answer, what is $n$? I.e. for a given t, how can I infer $n$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the $n$ in the math is the same as the `N` in your code sample? Assuming it is, you picked 100, but how did you chose this? Since in the discrete example in my question, all I have is a probability of arrival. So i would expect the continuous case to completely depend on the intensity of the poisson process. Hence i dont understand what `N` resp. $n$ is used for

Comment: $N$ is a large integer because we obviously can't simulate all the sequence of arrival times (it's infinite). @charelf